# How can I use Squeel with hstore in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, arel, hstore

I would like to use the Squeel gem (based on Arel) for my Rails app (v 3.2.6). My hstore column is called properties.

These work perfectly fine:

```
User.where{(firstname == 'Ryan') & (lastname == 'Bates')}
User.where{"properties @> ('male' => '1')"}
```

The second example is a plain Postgres query, because Squeel doesn't seem to support hstore functions.

These don't work:

```
User.where{"properties @> ('male' => '1')" & firstname == 'Ryan'}
User.where{("properties @> ('male' => '1')") & (firstname == 'Ryan')}
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `&' for "properties @> ('male' => '1')":String
```

I do understand the error, but I don't know how to capsule my hstore query. Is there a better way to build hstore queries with Squeel or Arel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squeel supports SQL literals by using backticks (`).

Something like the following might work:

```
Person.where{(id == my{@person.id}) & (`preferences @> send_me_junk_email=>yes`)}
```

When using backticks Squeel will drop down a layer of abstraction and execute the SQL directly.

http://erniemiller.org/2012/05/30/sql-literals-in-squeel-or-overriding-backticks-in-ruby/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [sequel hstore gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/sequel-hstore), this adds support for hStore to Sequel

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I have to change to Sequel.

Comment: You don't need the sequel hstore gem, Sequel has shipped with a pg_hstore extension that adds support for quite a few versions now.

Comment: I think you are confusing 'Squeel' with 'Sequel'.
The OP was asking about [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel)

Answer (score 1):

I just dug into this.  The answer seemed to be in [this file](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel/blob/master/lib/squeel/nodes/operators.rb), essentially you can add your own operations in here.

This example uses `@>` to hunt through PostgreSQL arrays ([demonstrated in this presentation](http://slid.es/danmcclain/supercharging-activerecord-with-postgresql)).

```
module Squeel
  module Nodes
    module Operators
      def within *list
        list = "{#{list.map(&:to_s).join(',')}}"
        Operation.new self, :'@>', list
      end
    end
  end
end
```

After putting this monkey-patch in, the following Squeel statement becomes possible, assuming there is a `Note` model which has a `tags` array field.

```
Note.where { tags.within 'first tag', 'second tag' }
```

Which should generate SQL that looks like this:

```
"SELECT \"notes\".* FROM \"notes\"  WHERE \"notes\".\"tags\" @> '{first tag,second tag}'"
```

Comment: Nice! Have you considered opening a pull request to contribute this functionality to Squeel?